# Spring form tag throws error in jsp page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to spring mvc and kind struggling to implement form using spring form tags. With little help I got spring tag lib working from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516801/spring-form-taglib-is-not-working#comment16851432_12516801)

The problem I have now is kind of weird, which I don't understand.

```
    <form:form>
     <table id="<portlet:namespace />AddEquipmentTable" cellpadding="3">
      <tr><td colspan="2"><label class="required">
           <fmt:message key="requiredFieldsTxt" /></label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td><%-- <form:label path="assetIdLabel"> --%><fmt:message key="assetIdTxt" /><%-- </form:label> --%></td>
          <td><input type="text" id="assetId" name="assetId" size="30" /></td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
       </tr> 
        .......
        .........

     </table>
   </form:form>
```

I have commented the  tag because when I uncomment it shows error in firebug

> SyntaxError: missing ; before statement Error 500:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain
>   target object for bean name 'command' available as request
>   attribute.

Can anyone help me with this. I am newbie, I am still trying to understand the working of spring mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="command">
</form:form>
```

command is the object which has to be added to modelandview.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="customerForm">
```

see http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-neither-bindingresult-nor-plain-target-object-for-bean-name-xxx-available-as-request-attribute/